# Terminal or settings issue

Tags: c++, terminal, config

I'm having an issue, maybe with g++ or the debugger, I don't know too much of this, just started coding.

Here is the issue:
[image]

The thing is, it is not displaying the "100 occurs 3 times", it just displays when I write another number:
[image]

Here is another example:
[image]

Not showing the output until I write another number:
[image]

**I'm I coding something wrong or is it something related to the settings of my PC or anything related, has anyone been in the same situation?**

Here is the code just if anyone wants to check it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    if (std::cin >> currVal)
    {
        int cnt = 1;

        while (std::cin >> val)
        {
            if (val == currVal)
            {
                ++cnt;
            }

            else
            {
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't ending the input. So the while statement is always true.

Comment: Expanding on above, until you give another input, `while (std::cin >> val)` is blocked waiting for that next input to see if it's the same number and needs t be added to the count or not. In both cases 0 isn't the same number, so the program prints out the count  and waits for another character to see if it's a 0.

Comment: A handy tool for figuring out stuff like this is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program line by line (instruction by instruction if you need that fine a grain) and watch what happens as it happens. When you see something unexpected, stop and figure it out because that's probably the first bug.

Comment: A debugger will show you exactly what your program is doing, and why. Have you tried using your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and see what's happening?

Comment: Okay, I got the part of ending the input, will look for that since I don't know how.

Comment: And yes! I used the debugger, it's very useful, but still didn't understand why wasn't it reading my last output. But with the first answer, I will take a look for that. Thanks!

Comment: The key combination to signal the end of user input depends on the terminal software used. Looking a lot like PowerShell in this case, so start with CTRL+Z.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301! That was the easiest one, but still have the doubt of ending the input as @ChrisMM said, but thanks!